# Default Integration server in Node is not showing IIB 10?

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I have downloaded "10.0.0.14-IIB-WIN64-DEVELOPER.exe" and installed it after opening it default user node is showing but default integration server is not showing. When deploying any integration service "No Integeration server available found" error is coming. when I tried to make new integration server it is giving following error .

```
Integration node rejected the request BIP1123E: The integration server already exists. The utility was asked to create integration server 'default2' on integration node 'TESTNODE_JA', but it already exists. Check that the names of the integration server and integration node are correct and reissue the command. or or No response from broker

Check that, 1. The integration node is running. 2. The TCP/IP port used by the integration node's web user interface is active. 3. The integration node name provided in the connection details matches the name of the integration node if the node is remote.
```

When I started it through command line following error came.

mqsicreateexecutiongroup.bat abc -e xyz BIP1124I: Creating integration server 'xyz' on integration node 'abc'... BIP1047E: The operation timed out waiting for a response. The utility did not receive an expected response from the integration node withi n a designated amount of time. The operation might have completed successfully, even though the response was not received.Ensure that the integration node is running and that the correct connection parameters have been supplied to the utility. Use the -w flag to increase the amount of time to wait for responses.

kindly help as i m new to IIB.

Comment: You should click edit and add more details to your question not try to add them in a comment where you can not format them.

Comment: Restart your toolkit. In windows run your toolkit as administrator.

Comment: restarted many times even installed and uninstalled it many times but integration server which is default is not coming

Answer (score 1):

You should check real status of your installation
Try to use command via IBM Integration Console 10.0.0.14 (you can find it in your Windows Start Menu), not a cmd.exe

type mqsilist - it should display all your integration nodes

```
 C:\Program Files\IBM\IIB\10.0.0.15>mqsilist
BIP1325I: Integration node 'TESTNODE_abc' with administration URI 'http://localhost:4414' is running.
BIP8071I: Successful command completion.
```

if you type mqsilist again with the name of integration node you should get the list of all integration servers within your integration node

```
  C:\Program Files\IBM\IIB\10.0.0.15>mqsilist TESTNODE_abc
-----------------------------------
BIP1286I: Integration server 'default' on integration node 'TESTNODE_abc' is running.
BIP8071I: Successful command completion.
```

It is possible to use web admin interface which is on URL listed in first mqsilist.

If there is nothing in your output, you can try to create integration server again and look into windows event viewer as is described in IBM Infocenter, there could be more information
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/an04090_.html